# Is this form generator a valid Composite GoF?

Tags: design-patterns, php, uml, composition

Searching for a good PHP real world example, I've found this [example](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/composite/php/example#example-1) of "composite" using:

- FormElement as **Component**
- Fieldset and Form as **Containers**
- Input as **Leaf**

(this is my UML from the code):

[image]

So, Is this form generator a valid Composite GoF?

Comment: Why does it matter? It is pretty unimportant if this is the GoF composite "by the book" or a variation of it which is not described in that book literally. What actually matters if it does fit to the requirements which are going to be solved by this model.

Comment: Because I am preparing classes about GoF Patterns using PHP

Comment: To me, it looks perfectly like a GoF composite. But for the purpose of teaching, you should make it clear that making the "Composite" (here the class `FieldComposite`) an abstract class is not part of the pattern, so a simpler example without two different `Composite`'s may be more suitable for your purpose.

Comment: I agree with Doc Brown.  It matters less that a particular example is "correct," and more that the example effectively solves a particular problem.  I also agree that a simpler example might be better, especially if they're not well-versed in forms, form elements and field sets.

Comment: Or, you could introduce the pattern with the Form being the composite (as a concrete class), and then organize an exercise around introducing requirements. E.g., ask them to add another leaf class (like a button) for an easier/warmup exercise. The next one, somewhat harder, would be to ask them to add a fieldset; let them figure it out and see what they'll do. They could decide to copy the existing approach and add the Fieldset as a separate derivative of FormElement; then maybe they'll see that they can extract and reuse the common code.

Comment: (And if the student's aren't going to be actually dealing with code, then you can guide them through the above process/excercises on a whiteboard or something, by changing up the diagram.)

Comment: To make your model language agnostic you would remove the "Extends" labels from the Generalizations (which is used in PHP and Java but not in many other languages),

Answer (score 1):

According to Gof the composite pattern aims to

> compose objects into tree structures to represent part-whole
>   hierarchies. Composite lets clients treat individual objects and
>   compositions of objects uniformly.

If we compare with your example, the GoF pattern involves:

- a `Component` that declares the common interface of all the objects in the structure.  In your case it's `FormElement`
- `Leaf` classes that implement the `Component` interface. In your case, it's `Input`.
- `Composite` classes that implement the `Component` interface and may have child components.  In your case, it's `FieldComposite`.  Your case adds a level of complexity by having an abstract composite, which can be specialises into `FieldSet` and `Form`.

So your class forms a good example of the GoF composite, without prejudice of  the following comments:

- renaming `FormElement` into `FormComponent` would facilitate mapping to the GoF participants.
- your class  `FormElement` does not implement the child management operations.  Although GoF suggest declaring them at Component level, it leaves it as open implementation question whether to do it at `Component` or `Composite` level.
- Normally the Component should also give an access to its children.  The default implementation thereof being that no children are returned.  Here you don't foresee to expose this access method at all.  But it doesn't hamper the pattern's intents.

Looking at your diagram, I wonder if `FieldComposite` offers a default implementation of `render()` or if `render()` should be shown abstract there as well (italics) since it'll be implemented by more specific subtypes.

***Remark***: Since you are looking for an example and not for a solution to a real world problem, I won‘t reiterate the advise to look more on how well a design solves your problem than on its compliance with known patterns. I nevertheless totally subscribe to this opinion.